# Swipe Refresh View's animation gettting stuck due to setAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am having Recycleview with pull to refresh functionality and by executing pull to refresh I am shuffling records in Recycleview

Now my issue is once I set the new array to the Recycleview by using pull to refresh the view. Here the Swipe Refresh view will get stuck in fact the whole Recycleview will get stuck due to the notifyDataSetChange() method this issue is there for only 1 or 2 seconds. Also, my number of records is the array is kind of 200 so might be that is also the case.

FYI: I can add a progress bar here for this task but I don't want to block user interaction so any help that I can set adapter without any lag/stuck issue in UI?

Adapter

```
public class BaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Context context;
    List<Model.Result> list;
    Controller controller;
    CommonFunctions cmf;
    String user_id;
    int layout;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public BaseAdapter(Context context, List<Model.Result> list, int layout, Controller controller) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.controller = controller;
        this.layout = layout;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder_ic)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder_ic)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
        cmf = new CommonFunctions(context);
        user_id = CommonFunctions.myPreference.getString(context, GlobalConstants.id);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int pos) {

        // holder.name.setText(list.get(pos).getCatName());
        if (holder.name != null)
            holder.name.setText(list.get(pos).getAudioName());
        if (holder.title != null)
            holder.title.setText(list.get(pos).getArtistName());
        if (holder.timeDuration != null)
            holder.timeDuration.setText(list.get(pos).getAudiolength());
        if(holder.txtTopicName!=null)
            holder.txtTopicName.setText(list.get(pos).getCatName());

        if (holder.image != null) {
          imageLoader.displayImage(list.get(pos).getAudioImage(), holder.image,options);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.TV_title) {

        }
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout ll_row;
        ImageView iv_more, image;
        TextView name, title, timeDuration,txtTopicName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ll_row = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
            iv_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_more);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            timeDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_duration);
            txtTopicName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTopicName);
        }
    }


}
```

Refresh View

```
binding.swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            binding.swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            if(array!=null&&array.size()>0){
                Collections.shuffle(array, new Random());
                binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter(getActivity(),array, layout,null));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do your shuffling on a background thread instead of UI thread.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with both the way but the issue happens when I set this array to the RecyclerView using setAdapter or if I just notifyAdapter with the new Array.

Comment: 200 items, are you loading item in a bg thread, once loaded use a handler with pos delay of 50ms to set new ArrayList and notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: @notTdar I am shuffling my array in a background thread but to set it on the recyclerview I am setting it on UI thread. The issue causes due setAdapter method if I set anything the UI gets stuck for a second

Comment: post your adapter code, it should not be happening

Comment: @notTdar posted

Comment: try to comment out this line and see `imageLoader.displayImage....`

Comment: @Zain tried but not worked

Comment: show me where you are setting new list, after swipe refresh done

Comment: @notTdar posted some code

Comment: @MohitDholakia, see the answer, create adapter instance once only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked in view binding but see below the line, the culprit.

```
   binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter(getActivity(),array, layout,null));
```

// that a heavy operation of creating a constructor and top of that 
look at your adapter class, how heavy.
Your Base adapter constructor seems heavy,

```
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() // heavy
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder_ic)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder_ic)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
```

I'd suggest, 
+ Next during the creation of your adapter, pass an empty list.

- Why don't you initialize DisplayImageOptions instance in Host class where you are creating adapter and pass an initialized instance to adapter.
- this way overhead is taken on host class not the adapter.
- and last, when swipe is done, a new lest is ready.

  mAdapter.setNewList(whatever list){
  this.yourList = newList;
  notifyDataSetChanged.
  }

This should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry still there is a minor lag while scrolling down after pull to refresh

Comment: oaky, that's another issue, create separate thread for that. so with the above solution does it help?